# How to import * as _ from "lodash" on Plunker platform?

Tags: angular, plunker

I am trying to load loadash in plunker and Angular2

I putting

```
import * as _ from "lodash";
```

but don't know what I should write in System.config so that it works.

Could someone please help?
https://plnkr.co/edit/gsfr1v?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can add this reference -

```
<script data-require="lodash.js@*" data-semver="2.4.1" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

Reference - [Lodash](http://embed.plnkr.co/wou4Vj/)

Thanks

Comment: I added as you recomended but still I get 404 error on that file.
I corrected also the link to https, as plunker ask for https.
any ideas? Updated link https://plnkr.co/edit/gsfr1v?p=preview

Comment: where are you getting 404? As I am not getting 404 anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>`

This script reference worked for me.